# Why is SharePoint 2016 User Profile service not importing updated user info from AD?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, active-directory-import

New users added to AD are imported successfully into SharePoint 2016.  Updating user information in AD (ex. title, department) does not get imported into SharePoint2016.  Not sure when this behavior started but has been going on for a few months.    SharePoint 2016 sits on Windows 2016.  Only changes would be installing server and SharePoint 2016 patches.  UPS is started and we are using AD Import.  The service account associated with UPS has full control of the site web app and mysites.  I have not been able to locate any errors.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a support case with Microsoft and the tech stated SharePoint Active Directory Import will only import users from AD if all Users and Containers are selected under the Users Container.  I selected all Users and Containers and importing worked.  However, the Employee Directory displayed all this information which is not needed.  To get around this I changed the query text under People Search Core results to {searchboxquery} @emailaddress.com.  It appears only users with a company email address are searchable, which is what we want.